# How can I use data from a multidimensional array to the style of a div IF the divID matches a string in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, setattribute

I'm fairly new at this and would like some help.

Let's say I have a multidimensional array that collects btnID, color and opacity.
I have 26 buttons with labeled btn1 to btn26 that I would like to change the style to the styleSet if the button id matches.

I know I have to use a loop. So here's what I'm thinking and where I need help.

```
var styleSet = [['btn5', 'green', .7], ['btn11', 'red', .3], ['btn18', 'blue', .7]];

for (var i = 0; i < styleSet.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById(styleSet[i][0]).setAttribute('color', styleSet[i][1], 'opacity', styleSet[i][2]);
  }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute  The documentation does not show that you can update more than one thing at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First If you want to set Styles you have to use `style`. And Also I added a validation in case some `IDs` do not exist.

```js
var styleSet = [['btn5', 'green', .7], ['btn11', 'red', .3], ['btn18', 'blue', .7]];

for (var i = 0; i < styleSet.length; i++) {
if(document.getElementById(styleSet[i][0])){
document.getElementById(styleSet[i][0]).style.color = styleSet[i][1];
document.getElementById(styleSet[i][0]).style.opacity = styleSet[i][2]
}
}
```

```html
<button id='btn11'>
  testButton
</button>
<button id='btn5'>
  testButton2
</button>
```